# Whats the new max_tag_id value for pagination set by Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am creating app where I use Instagram API to display images filtered by Tag, date and likes. Previously, to filter date instagram used to append the epoch time with max_tag_id and min_tag_id. Now, the format has changed:

```
"pagination":  {
  "next_max_tag_id": "962224976421224235",
  "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
  "next_max_id": "962224976421224235",
  "next_min_id": "962225472549366575",
  "min_tag_id": "962225472549366575",
  "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nyc/media/recent?client_id=02e15f8b37f34d1f8da7ddcb0a55bae6&max_tag_id=962224976421224235"
}
```

**max_tag_id=962224976421224235**

How is max_tag_id calculated now? Instagram has not updated it's API doc on the same. Also, [gramfeed.com](http://gramfeed.com) had implemented the date filtering functionality but now they have disabled it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the new `max_tag_id` is the `media_id` of the next photo.

So in your case, if you make a request with the next_url, the first photo in the response will have the id 962224976421224235, (the actual id will look like xxx_xxxx which is `mediaId_userId`)

Cannot do time filter anymore :(, so I disabled it in http://gramfeed.com